# Custom Post Type UI for custom tables

Tags: admin-ui

I am working on a plugin and I like to utilize the WordPress's native admin UI for post listing and post editing screen for my own data structure.

Does anybody has an idea or guidelines please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are built with [WP_List_Table class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table), but can be re-built visually (no ordering/filtering built in) by copying html.

The post list and the posts edit screens for custom post types will be the standard UI - its your metaboxes that will require some manual copying of Wordpress styles.

There's these site and project that helps with classes and colours:

- https://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com
- https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Using web browser inspector you can find the classnames of Wordpress elements and reuse them, for example for grey vs blue main buttons it's: `.button` and `.button.button-primary.button-large`